# "nth row" excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to get value of nth row in excel. It should be easy with offset function, but Its not working for me.

I have 2 tables in 2 files, lets call those "Tab1" and "Tab2".

```
Tab1 = result table
Tab2 = data table
```

Tab1 Build:
I need to put data in rows:

```
A12, A14, A16 (+2).
```

First value I need to insert there is A18 from Tab2.
and then +24 (A18, A42, A66, A90, A114 ...).

```
A12 = A18
A14 = A42
A16 = A66
```

etc.

I write this:

```
=OFFSET('[Tab2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$18;(ROW('[Tab2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1)-1)*24;0)
because I want start from A18, and then use +24 step.
```

But its not working :/
Any ideas where I made mistake?

Comment: `ROW()` should use current row (no arguments) to increment. The fixed location you have will only ever return a specific value

Comment: `=OFFSET('[Tab2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$18;((ROW()-12)/2)*24;0)`

Comment: But Row of current Sheet (so if its in Tab1, then it would act as A12 (tab1) ?